# Insert or replace não funciona

Tags: android, sqlite

O comando

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO SYSVAL ( CDDEVICE, DTVALINI, DTVALFIM, 
SALDO, REALTIME, VALIDADO ) VALUES( '34322910071833580','31-08-2016',
'31-08-2016','10','63714560','S')
```

funciona sem problemas no SQLiteStudio, mas não funciona quando executado pela aplicação no Android.

Apesar de não causar erro algum, a tabela continua vazia.

Alterei o código de inserção para algo assim:

```
        Boolean result = false;
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("CDDEVICE", valores[0].toString());
        values.put("DTVALINI", valores[1].toString());
        values.put("DTVALFIM", valores[2].toString());
        values.put("SALDO", valores[3].toString());
        values.put("REALTIME", valores[4].toString());
        values.put("VALIDADO", valores[5].toString());


        try{
            db.insertOrThrow("SYSVAL", null, values);
            result = true;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

E aí funcionou sem problemas.

Alguém poderia me dizer porque o primeiro comando não esta funcionando?

A estrutura da tabela SYSVAL é a seguinte:

```
sqlString = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SYSVAL (" +
                    "    CDDEVICE   VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL," +
                    "    DTVALINI   DATE," +
                    "    DTVALFIM   DATE," +
                    "    SALDO      INT," +
                    "    REALTIME   NUMERIC(15)," +
                    "    VALIDADO   VARCHAR(1)," +
                    "    CONSTRAINT SYSVAL_PK PRIMARY KEY ( CDDEVICE )  "+
                    ");";
```

Estou executando o comando que não funciona desse modo:

```
 public Boolean executacomando( SQLiteDatabase db, String comando  )
    {
        Boolean result = false;

        try {
            db.rawQuery( comando,  null );
            result = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

O metodo retorna true normalmente, mas o insert não acontece.

Comment: O método `insertOrThrow()` não é equivalente a **INSERT OR REPLACE INTO**

Comment: Ele postou insertOrThrow() como teste e demonstrar que por esse método funciona, @ramaral

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo, poste a estrutura da tabela. Poste o DDL da tabela.

Comment: @DanielOmine se existir um registo com a mesma chave primária ele irá dar erro.

Comment: sim.. precisa ter uma chave primária única.. mas ele comenta que no sqlitestudio funciona.. Então pode ser que a estrura do ambiente de teste esteja diferente do que está no app.. dificil determinar sem os detalhes

Comment: Tem de mostrar como usou o **INSERT OR REPLACE INTO** no código.

Comment: Obrigado pelo tempo de vocês. Fiz as alterações solicitadas.

Comment: O codigo para criar a tabela no SQLiteStudio é o mesmo que estou utilizando para criar a tabela no aplicativo.

Comment: Não sei porque não funciona, mas o método de SQLiteDatabase equivalente a **INSERT OR REPLACE INTO** é [replace](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#replace%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29)

Comment: Realmente seria interessante se existe o UPSERT no sqlite. =D

Comment: Acho que eu descobri onde estou comendo bola.

Comment: Pronto funcionou. Alterei o código que estava errado.

Answer (score 1):

Para executar o comando `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO` devemos usar `db.execSQL( comando )` e não `db.rawQuery( comando,  null );` como esta no código.